# don't work "js click()" in user script on site yandex

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts, yandex

I'm trying to simulate a mouse click on the central panel on the website `https://translate.yandex.ru/ocr`

I open devtools
I use the following code

```
const b = document.querySelector('.dropBlock-dropMessage')
```

I see the element
I’ll write further

```
b.click()
```

and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the event handler they use is keypress or something

Comment: @mplungjan for example?

Comment: I am not going to Yandex to find out. Use the debugger  to find out